# How To Implement Sections with NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsfetchrequest, sections

I've done some reading up on multiple similar issues and sites and I just cannot make any understanding of this.

I have a NSFetchedResultsController which displays information from a user adding information into a ModalViewController with text fields. The user is presented with a ModalView and they put in some words into the fields, click save and that makes up the single sectioned row of tables in the TableView, which implements the NSFetchedResultsController protocol.

What I would like to do now is:

- On one of the text fields, be able to create a new section out of the information provided in that one textField.

My fetchrequest is:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Transaction" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"whoBy.name" ascending:YES selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];
    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

    NSFetchedResultsController *theFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];
    self.fetchedResultsController = theFetchedResultsController;
    _fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
    return _fetchedResultsController;
```

The attribute I want to do display is occasion.date, which means it is a relationship from the Transaction entity to the Occasion Entity (occasion) and the createdDate is an attribute on the Occasion entity.

I can see the sectionNameKeyPath:nil needs to be updated, but what do I update it to, and also do I have to change any of the datasource methods, titles, etc?

Any help on this would be massively appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The precise answer depends on what should be displayed as section headers and how the
sections should be sorted.

But generally, you have to add a property to the entity, which is then used as `sectionNameKeyPath` parameter. In addition, you have to add a *first sort descriptor*
using the same key (this condition can be relaxed slightly).

For example, if you simply add a string attribute `sectionName` to the entity and use
that as `sectionNameKeyPath` and as the first sort descriptor key, then all objects
with the same value for `sectionName` will be grouped into one section,
and the sections will be sorted by `sectionName`.
The remaining
sort descriptors are used to sort the objects within each section.

Another example would be to define a separate entity "Section" with a string attribute
"title" and an integer attribute "index", add a to-one relationship "section" from
"Transaction" to "Section", and use `section.index` as `sectionNameKeyPath`.
Again, all objects with the same section are grouped together, but the sections are
now sorted by the value of `section.index`, and you can modify
`tableView:titleForHeaderInSection:` so that the *title* is displayed in the section
header instead of the *index*.

This is quite general, but I hope that it gets you started.

Comment: Thanks for your help Martin - that does make sense, just the implementation is a bit harder..

Just as a trial, I've set my name attribute as the sectionNameKeyPath.. so that's @"whoBy.name" where whoBy is a relationshiop from Transaction to the Person Entity calling the name attribute.. 

I then have the following as the titleForHeaderInSection:
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [[[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section] name];
}

I'm getting only one section with one row.. do you have any thoughts?

Comment: should the sectionNamekeyPath be: sectionNameKeyPath:@"whoBy.name" , that is the first (and only) sortDescriptor in my fetchRequest.. I feel I'm getting there and am almost there.. but just need a bit of guidance - thanks !

Comment: @amitsbajaj: With sectionNameKeyPath and first sort descriptor set to @"whoBy.name" all transactions with the same value for "whoBy.name" should be grouped into the same section. If there are different names then you should have multiple sections. Perhaps check if numberOfSections and numberOfRowsInSection is implemented correctly.

Comment: thanks for the prompt reply - funnily enough, numberOfSections was missing completely! When I put that in, it now runs smoothly :) I'll be adjusting this now to reflect the user-chosen Date which would be so much better, but you helping me with this step has allowed for immense progress! Thanks again Martin :)

Comment: Actually - to just quickly ask you... the attribute I'm putting as the section title has nothign to do with the first sortDescriptor - do I then have to do anything special with that?

Comment: @amitsbajaj: What is your sectionNameKeyPath and what should the section title be?

Comment: sectionNameKeyPath:@"occasion.dateOfEvent" - the section title should be March 2013, Feb, etc. It's actually et as an attribute with the NSDate format right now, but I'm going to change that to string to make sure I know what I'm doing first..

the SortDescription is "whoBy.name", so different to the sectionNameKeyPath

Comment: @amitsbajaj: The first sort descriptor *has to* use the same key as sectionNameKeyPath.

Comment: Thanks Martin.. I've managed to get it working with NSSortDescriptor:@"whoBy.name" with sectionNameKeyPath:@"occasion.dateOfEvent" and so when I add that entry, it creates the sections appropriately - I still need to get that working beyond a NSString and with a date, so users are not just typing in "September 2013". Not sure why it worked though with the NSSortDescriptor and the sectionNameKeyPath being different.. but I'll keep playing - for now, I'm thankful for you assistance on this Martin.. your continued assistance!

Comment: @amitsbajaj: If my answer helped, it would be nice if you "accept" it. Otherwise you can add more information to the question and I will try to help.

Comment: oops, my apologies Martin - I thought I had done that! Sorry, I will do that now - it helped massively - thanks again!